# How to remove some link type in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I made all URLs clickable by:

```
(define-globalized-minor-mode global-goto-address-mode goto-address-mode goto-address-mode)
(global-goto-address-mode)
```

However, when I have a shell command with "service:" substring, Emacs treats it as a link incorrectly.  How can I remove that link type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs 27.1 makes this a bit more configurable via the two new variables:

- `goto-address-uri-schemes-ignored`
- `goto-address-uri-schemes`

You should set only one of the two and, per the docstrings, must do so *before* the `goto-addr` library is loaded.  This is because the new variables are only intermediate values<sup>1</sup> which are used when defining `goto-address-url-regexp` -- which (as before) is the only value which is ultimately used by the library.

If you wish to change the behaviour *after* loading `goto-addr` then you need to re-generate or otherwise set `goto-address-url-regexp`, exactly the same as in earlier versions.  See [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36797142/324105) for an example of doing this.

---

<sup>1</sup> Specifically, `goto-address-uri-schemes-ignored` affects the *default* value of `goto-address-uri-schemes`, which in turn affects the *default* value of `goto-address-url-regexp`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```el
(setq goto-address-url-regexp
      (concat "\\<"
              (regexp-opt (cl-delete-if
                           (lambda (x)
                             (member x '("mailto:" "data:" "service:")))
                           (copy-sequence thing-at-point-uri-schemes))
                          :paren)
              thing-at-point-url-path-regexp))
```

This should also fix bugs in the original regexp, so it could match some new things as well, but probably nothing you're worried about ("svn+ssh://" and "bzr+ssh://" will match now, and a few others will be more constrained where dots are concerned. Basically the original code didn't regexp-quote the schemes!)

Note that "mailto:" and "data:" were being excluded in the original.

Comment: n.b. I'll report this bug if it's still present in the upstream code.

Comment: See bug #23343.